# Reprint column with modifications

Tags: awk, sed, cut, tr

I have a file that looks like this:

```
lbsrv_standards-d
lbsrv_standards-t
lbsrv_standards
```

Desired output:

```
rename lbsrv_standards-d lb_standards-d
rename lbsrv_standards-t lb_standards-t
rename lbsrv_standards lb_standards
```

So I need to print $1, a space and then print a modified version of $1, I've been using awk but I can't figure out the substitution without adding a newline between the original and modified $1s.

Solution:

```
awk '{print "rename "$1} ; { gsub("lbsrv", "lb", $1) ; print }'
```

Output:

```
rename lbsrv_standards-d 
lb_standards-d
rename lbsrv_standards-t 
lb_standards-t
rename lbsrv_standards 
lb_standards
```

Any assistance would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
awk  '{a=$0; sub(/^lbsrv/, "lb", a); print "rename "$0" "a }'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/dTsxUX)

**Details**

- `a=$0` - a temporary variable is declarted with the value of the whole line
- `sub(/^lbsrv/, "lb", a)` - the `lbsrv` at the start of the string is replaced with `lb`
- `print "rename "$0" "a` - prints the result: `rename`, space, the whole line, space and then the contents of the `a` variable.

A simpler solution is possible with `sed` (especially if the strings come in individually):

```
sed 's~^lbsrv\(.*\)~& lb\1~' file > newfile
```

See [this `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/R7d2Ct)

This is a BRE POSIX pattern based `sed` command that finds

- `^` - start of a line
- `lbsrv` - substring
- `\(.*\)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars up to the end of the line/input.

The `& lb\1` is a replacement pattern that takes the whole line first, then appends a space, `lb` and then the contents of Group 1.

Answer (score 1):

***1st Solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"}{print "rename",$0,"lb_"$2}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of above code now.

```
awk '                           ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                          ##Starting BEGIN section here.
  FS="_"                        ##Setting field separator as _ here.
}                               ##Closing BEGIN section of awk command here.
{
  print "rename",$0,"lb_"$2     ##Printing string rename then complete line then lb_ string with 2nd column here as per OP need.
}'  Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***2nd solution:*** Adding a `sed` solution now.

```
sed 's/\([^_]*\)_\(.*\)/rename \1_\2 lb_\2/'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
rename lbsrv_standards-d lb_standards-d
rename lbsrv_standards-t lb_standards-t
rename lbsrv_standards lb_standards
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine, but just so you can see that all you needed to do was to use `printf` instead of `print`:

```
$ awk '{printf "rename %s ", $1} ; { gsub("lbsrv", "lb", $1) ; print }' file
rename lbsrv_standards-d lb_standards-d
rename lbsrv_standards-t lb_standards-t
rename lbsrv_standards lb_standards
```

Of course normally you would combine the commands in a single action:

```
$ awk '{printf "rename %s ", $1; gsub("lbsrv", "lb", $1) ; print }' file
```

Also, `gsub` operates on `$0` by default, and it's fashionable to use a trailing `1` instead of `print`, so finally:

```
$ awk '{printf "rename %s ", $1; gsub("lbsrv", "lb")}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

if creating the output means to an end to actually rename the files, you can instead do this:

```
$ rename lbsrv_ lb_ lbsrv_standards{-d,-t,}
```

will do the prefix renaming on the specified three files (after bash brace expansion).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/lbsrv\(.*\)/rename & lb\1/p;d' file
```

Use pattern matching to identify the parts of the line that need replicating and print a successful match, otherwise delete the line.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
 perl -pe ' s/lb(?:srv)(.*)/rename $& lb$1/g '
```

with your given inputs

```
$ cat jim.txt
lbsrv_standards-d
lbsrv_standards-t
lbsrv_standards

$ perl -pe ' s/lb(?:srv)(.*)/rename $& lb$1/g ' jim.txt
rename lbsrv_standards-d lb_standards-d
rename lbsrv_standards-t lb_standards-t
rename lbsrv_standards lb_standards

$
```